# Hours Calculations in Excel 2010

Tags: excel

I have an Excel 2010 workbook which contains a cell with the value of, say, `9876:54:32` (manually entered) representing 9876 hours, 54 minutes and 32 seconds of, say, phone talk time.

Then I have a cell with the value of, say, `1000` (manually entered) representing 1000 calls.

I want to divide the values to get the average talk time of 592.615 minutes per call.

I'm doing a regular =A1/B1 and it gives me an error.

*** EDITED ***
Thanks Brain Webster for correcting my math. I mean 9.876 hours. But the point is that Excel gives me an error, not my manual math. Playing around with it I discovered that Excel is fine with me with values up to `9999:59:59`. Once I try with 10000:00:00 and up, it doesn't recognize it as a time value.

Comment: It is working fine for me in the same Office version. What error are you getting?

Comment: I think your math is wrong. I get 592.61 minutes per call.

Comment: When you get an error - always share it. Tested this on Excel07, works fine. `9876:54:32` in a cell formatted as `[h]:mm:ss`, divided by 1000 results to `9:52:37`, which is correct.

Comment: Thanks Brain Webster for correcting my math. I hat mean 9.876 hours. But the point is that Excel gives me an error, not my manual math. Playing around with it I discovered that Excel is fine with me with values up to 9999:59:59. Once I try with 10000:00:00 and up, it doesn't recognize it as a time value.

Comment: well, ok, but this a whole different problem, than the dividing stuff ;) and by the way, it is still possible - type in 511.5275704 in a cell, then format this cell as [h]:mm:ss or use it with `=B1` in an already formatted cell

Comment: @Jook - well, NOW I know it's a different problem! Since all my numbers where greater than 10k hours, I thought it was a dividing problem. Now, how do I know the value to enter. For example, one value I have is 10971:12:14. Thanks.

Comment: well, this might change your whole situation, because, when all your numbers are greater than 10k, and you only have this `109:12:14` format, then it is always interpreted as text, as K_B pointed out. So, to save you complex formulars, I would recommend, you add three cols to parse the time into minutes, hours and seconds. Or, as always - VBA :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I love these seemingly easy riddles, so here is my solution as a formula and as a VBA attempt:

my original:

```
= (LINKS(A38;FINDEN(":";A38)-1)/24)+ZEITWERT("0"&RECHTS(A38;LÄNGE(A38)-FINDEN(":";A38)+1))
```

translated:

```
= (LEFT(A38,FIND(":",A38)-1)/24)+TIMEVALUE("0"&RIGHT(A38,LEN(A38)-FIND(":",A38)+1))
```

This will get you the right value to a given 10k text of a time duration. You would only have to setup the format of the cell to `[h]:mm:ss`. Then those values will look the same, but one would be a string and the other a number - and that is a major difference ;)

In vba it looks much more easier, and once defined, you can use it as a worksheetfunction.

```
Public Function GetDurationValue(ByVal strInput As String) As Double
  Dim arrResult As Variant

  arrResult = Split(strInput, ":") 'saves you parsing
  GetDurationValue = (arrResult(0) / 24) + _
                     TimeSerial(0, arrResult(1), arrResult(2))

End Function


A38 = "10971:12:14"
=GetDurationValue(A38)
=457.13349537037
```

Comment: +1 @Jook - I edited your translation to show LEN not LENGTH, also perhaps a little easier would be this version `=LEFT(A1,FIND(":",A1)-1)/24+("0:"&REPLACE(A1,1,FIND(":",A1),""))`

Comment: @Jook - thanks for your simple formula answer. Sorry for the delay, but I was more than 8 days without power in New York!

Answer (score 1):

You can use LEFT and RIGHT function to retreive parts of the time value and then sum and multiply these values by 60 [minutes] (resp. 3600 [hours]).

Something like this for the hours, minutes, seconds (A1 is the cell with time value):

```
B1=VALUE(LEFT(A1;FIND(":";A1)))*3600
B2=VALUE(LEFT(A1;FIND(":";A1; FIND(":";A1))))*60
B3=VALUE(LEFT(A1;FIND(":";A1; FIND(":";A1; FIND(":";A1)))))
```

Now you can sum that:

```
C1=SUM(B1;B2;B3)
```

Then divede by calls count (A2 is the cell with the calls count):

```
D1=C1/A2
```

Finally format it like time:

```
E1=TEXT(D1/(24*3600);"d \day\s hh:mm:ss")
```

BTW: I tried that in Excel 2013 and when I enter 111:22:33 into a cell it automatically converts to a time. So then I can divide it like you try...

Comment: I entered =VALUE(LEFT(A1;FIND(":";A1)))*3600 into a cell and it gives an error. I tries with , instead of ; and it sill gives an error.

Comment: LEFT(A1;FIND(":";A1)) includes the : so using VALUE on that will always give you an error, you need a -1 in there like LEFT(A1;FIND(":";A1)-1) - but see my suggestion for a simple(?!) one cell formula....

Answer (score 1):

It appears that hours > 10000 are not recognised as such by Excel. Therefore we need to introduce an `IF()` to see whether this is the case and determined the alternative formula for the case where hours >10000

`=IF(ISERROR(FIND(":",A2)),A2/B2, <SCRIPT IN CASE OF >10000>)`

`<SCRIPT IN CASE OF >10000>` will now be:

`VALUE(LEFT(A2,FIND(":",A2)))/24+VALUE(LEFT(A2,FIND(":",A2, FIND(":",A2))))/(24*60)+VALUE(LEFT(A2,FIND(":",A2, FIND(":",A2,FIND(":",A2)))))*(24*60*60)`

combine and enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't exceed `100,000` hours in A1, and you always display hours, minutes and seconds then this formula should suffice

`=IFERROR(A1/B1,(LEFT(A1)*10000/24+RIGHT(A1,10))/B1)`

format result cell as [h]:mm:ss to get the result as a time value

With `10971:12:14` in A1 and `1000` in B1 that should give a result of `10:58:16` [or format result cell as `[m]:ss` to get minutes and seconds like `658:16`]

This version will work with any number of hours and with or without seconds

`=IFERROR(A1/B1,(LEFT(A1,FIND(":",A1)-1)/24+RIGHT(A1&IF(COUNTIF(A1,":*:"),"",":00"),5)/60)/B1)`